# What is wrong with my fopen() PHP

Tags: php, fopen

I've got this variable which I want to save which is:

```
$counter = $counter['counter']++;
```

to make it so that it increments when I refresh the page.
Therefore, I decided to use the fopen, override the $counter variable and then save it.
I am still a beginner and I do not know how the fopen, fgets, fclose works.

So I wrote something like this.

```
$fp = fopen("file.php","r");
fwrite($fp, $counter);
fclose($fp);
```

So I wanted to open the file(file.php)(the file which is I am writing this code FYI), and then override the variable after it had been incremented and then save it by closing.

But the code doesn't seem to want to work and the variable does not seem to want to increment.
What am I doing wrong?
Do I want to have this $counter in a different file and pull the variable from there.

FYI: I don't want to use session_start() and $_SESSION because I am using cron job and it will not work.

**EDIT**

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT MIN(ID) AS min, MAX(ID) AS max FROM ytable') or exit(mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 

if($counter['counter'] < $row['max']){
    if (isset($counter['counter'])){
        $counter = $counter['counter']++;

    }else{
            $counter = $counter['counter'] = 0;
        }
 }
```

This is more of the code for those who are confused

Comment: What do sessions have to do with cron jobs? You're comparing cows to elephants there. And why are you setting `$counter` to some element of the array it used to be? We need more code to go on

Comment: `'r' Open for reading only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file.` Use `w` for writing, a DB would be better for this. Also where are you incrementing previous value? A possible simpler alternative is `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`.

Comment: you jsut counting visitors? google analytics or an Apache access log analyzer like awstats

Comment: @Harshit What I want to do is to when I run the php script, I want the $counter to increment and then save it by using fsomething() so it keeps on incrementing like (1, refresh, 2, refresh, 3) Get the point?

Comment: Is this specific to a user viewing a page or in general how many times the page is viewed?

Comment: It's not a visitor counter at all. It is supposed to increment so I can echo the next thing from the array which looks like $array[$counter]. If you get it?

Comment: @chris85 I understand your logic, but I do not know how to write it, so can you write it for me down below?

Comment: file opened in read mode and you are trying to write in it

Comment: I was not suggesting it was a visitor counter I was asking if the count in the file is per user. So if user A starts refreshing 5 time and user B comes in and does 5 refreshes is that counter=10 or 5 per user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read file like this. Open the file with previous counter & fetch the counter, increment it like this

```
$counter = readfile("file.php");
$counter++;
```

To write to the file, open the file in write mode like this

```
$fp = fopen("file.php","w");
fwrite($fp, $counter);
fclose($fp);
```

Is that result you are looking for ?

As chris85 suggested, database is used for this kind of cases. Better to use database instead of file handling.

Answer (score 1):

So say you have `file.txt` and that contains `5`. In that same directory you have `script.php`; this file would have

```
$counter = file_get_contents('file.txt'); // this takes in whatever value is in the file e.g in this case '5'
$counter++; // increment the value by 1 so we are now at 6
file_put_contents('file.txt', $counter); //write the value '6' back to the file
```

`file.txt` would then have `6`, after the first load.

Comment: Do you have to put file_get_content into a variable?

Comment: The function itself or the value being written? Not the function itself. See the manual for a longer write up of it, it executes when it is called. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: $check = file_get_contents('counter.php');
if($check < $row['max']){
 if (isset($check)){
  $counter2 = $check++;
      
    }else{
      $counter2 = $check = 0;
     }
 }
 file_put_contents('counter.php', $counter2);

Comment: I've just got $counter2; in the counter.php

Comment: Is that your whole code? If so you need to close `if($check < $row['max']){ `

Comment: It is closed. Forgot to put it in

Comment: `counter.php` has an integer or `$counter2`? Syntax looks right. You are only writing if the file's value is less than the max row, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, should be integer value, you are trying to increment it in script. The `file_get_contents` puts the value of the file into the variable.

Comment: Oh, I see confusion know I misread your first comment. Thought you said `Do you have to put file_put_content into a variable`. I'll update answer with comments in code.

Comment: Should it be a text file? not a php file

Comment: It can be any file type, it doesn't care it will try to read it. An actual `doc` wont work though unless you know how to decompile it. Make sure executing user has read an write privileges.

Comment: Fiddle around with it, post if you have questions. I'll answer tomorrow.